# Using 2 models in Django CreateView with input fields for only 1 model

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I am trying to make a page like this where the quotes are randomly picked from quotes.models.Quote using classmethod `Quote.get_random()`:

```
Quote1... by Author1
Quote2... by Author2

RichTextfield for user to comment on the quotes.
```

The user should not be able to edit the quotes in this page, just the comment. But I want the relationship between the quotes and user's comment to be saved.

I've looked at previous questions and answers but those were for using multiple forms in a view and the user can edit all fields. I also looked at package https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html but I don't think it helps my problem.

I am stuck at displaying the quotes and passing the selected quotes to the form to be saved. Can someone help or suggest how I can make progress?

Screenshot of page:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AKbP.png]

Using `{% get_quotes %}` in the post.html template, I get a list of dictionary for the quotes (as shown in screenshot). `{% get_quotes 3 %}` also works to generate 3 quotes.

```
[{'id': 81, 'text': '..., 'tags': [76, 77]}, {'id': 75, 'text': ..., 'tags': [74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81]}]
```

But nothing happens when I try to loop through the list.

```
{% for quote in get_quotes %}
    {{ quote }}
{% endfor %}
```

quotes.models.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.db import models
from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey
from modelcluster.models import ClusterableModel
from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager
from taggit.models import TagBase, ItemBase
from wagtail.snippets.models import register_snippet

from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from itertools import chain

import sys

sys.path.append("..")  # Adds higher directory to python modules path.


def to_dict(instance):
    opts = instance._meta
    data = {}
    for f in chain(opts.concrete_fields, opts.private_fields):
        data[f.name] = f.value_from_object(instance)
    for f in opts.many_to_many:
        data[f.name] = [i.id for i in f.value_from_object(instance)]
    return data


class Quote(ClusterableModel):
    text = RichTextField(
        config_name="awesome_ckeditor", help_text="You must enter some quote content"
    )
    author = models.CharField(
        max_length=300, blank=True, help_text="Person who said/wrote this quote"
    )
#snipped

    @classmethod
    def get_random(cls, n=2):
        """Returns a number of random quotes."""
        import random

        n = int(n)  # Number of quotes to return. Default n=2
        last = cls.objects.count() - 1
        selection = random.sample(range(0, last), n)
        random_quotes = []
        for each in selection:
            pk = cls.objects.filter(active=True)[each].pk
            random_quotes.append(to_dict(cls.objects.get(pk=pk)))
        return random_quotes

    def __str__(self):
        """String repr of this class."""
        return f"{self.text} - {self.author}"

    class Meta:

        verbose_name = "Quote"
        verbose_name_plural = "Quotes"
        ordering = ("author", "text")
```

create.models.py

```
from userauth.models import CustomUser


class UserPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publish = models.DateField(
        default=timezone.now,
        validators=[
            MinValueValidator(
                timezone.now().date(), message="The date cannot be in the past!"
            )
        ],
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ("draft", "Draft"),
        ("published", "Published"),
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default="draft")
    active = models.BooleanField(
        default=True, help_text="Allows moderator to unpublish posts if set to false"
    )  # Allows moderators to hide offensive posts
    inactive_message = models.TextField(
        max_length=500,
        blank=True,
        help_text="Enter the reason for setting this post to inactive",
    )
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=300, unique_for_date="publish", help_text="You must enter a title"
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=350, unique_for_date="publish")
    content = RichTextField(
        config_name="awesome_ckeditor", help_text="You must enter some content"
    )
    quotes = ParentalManyToManyField("quotes.Quote", related_name="user_posts")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            # Newly created object, so set slug
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        return super(UserPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(
            "create:detail",
            kwargs={
                "year": self.publish.year,
                "month": self.publish.month,
                "day": self.publish.day,
                "slug": self.slug,
            },
        )
```

templatetags.create_tags.py

```
from django import template

from quotes.models import Quote

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_quotes(n=2):
    return Quote.get_random(n)
```

views.py

```
from .models import UserPost


class OwnerMixin(object):
    """Returns only user's objects to prevent others from accessing."""

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(user=self.request.user)


class OwnerEditMixin(object):
    """Sets user pk"""

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy(
            "create:user_post_detail",
            kwargs={
                "year": self.object.publish.year,
                "month": self.object.publish.month,
                "day": self.object.publish.day,
                "slug": self.object.slug,
            },
        )


class UserPostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, OwnerEditMixin, CreateView):
    model = UserPost
    fields = ["publish", "status", "title", "content"]
    template_name = "create/post.html"

    def get_form(self):
        form = super().get_form()
        form.fields["publish"].widget = DateInput(attrs={"type": "date"})
        return form
```